# System.Net.FtpWebRequest GetDateTimestamp example

Tags: .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm looking for a short bit of sample code which uses the `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` namespace to get the timestamp of a specified remote file on an FTP server. I know I need to set the `Method` property of my request object to `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp` but I'm not sure how to get the response back into a `System.DateTime` object.

Comment: See also [Download files from FTP if they are created within the last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10121911/850848).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep - thats pretty much what I ended up with. I went with something like this

```cs
request = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.whatever.com/somefile.txt");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
request.Proxy = null;

using (FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
        Console.WriteLine(resp.LastModified);
}
```

Comment: One problem with this approach - it automatically converts the time to the client's current time zone, not the server's time zone. I found that I needed to use WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails and parse the time out of the line that the file is found on in order to get the modified date of the server's time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```cs
DateTime DateValue;    

FtpWebRequest Request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yourUri);
Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
Request.UseBinary = false;

using (FtpWebResponse Response = (FtpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
using (TextReader Reader = new StringReader(Response.StatusDescription))
{
    string DateString = Reader.ReadLine().Substring(4);
    DateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the date field only but not the time, do exactly as the first answer in this thread with the following exception:

```
Console.WriteLine(response.LastModified().ToShortDateString);
```