# Edit text file residing on Network (LAN)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text-files

I want to access and edit the text file from c# application which is on network and accessed through ip address. There are no credentials required to access the files so i want some sample code or guide on how can i begin to achieve this task. The file i want to edit is on Android Tablet and the storage of the android application (SD card) i am accessing through ip address as my machine and Android device are on same network.
thanks

```
  try
        {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("192.168.1.2/NewFolder/TickerText.txt");

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null) 
            {
                //write the lie to console window
                textBox1.Text=line;
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ae)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ae.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Have you written code to access a local file? Do you have a specific problem with accessing network files? You need to tell us what it is you need to know.

Comment: This does not show any kind of research effort. -1

Comment: Can you establish SMB connections between the two machines? Are you able to create an application to edit a local file? If 2x yes: Use the same techniques to edit the file remotely.

Comment: I am able to edit the local file on my drive. I want to edit the file over ftp accessing the folders via ip address as it is on network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both computers are windows, you can share the folder that the file is in and access it for writing using:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"\\IPADDRESS\directories\file.txt") 
{
    writer.Write("Word ");
}
```

and for reading using:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"\\IPADDRESS\directories\file.txt");
```

Same as any other file reader / writer.

---

With the additional information involving the android operating system the file is on, and the inclusion of FTP I can only say that

- [simple-ftp-get-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053513/howto-do-a-simple-ftp-get-file-on-android)
- [net-ftpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040371/system-net-ftpwebrequest-getdatetimestamp-example)
- [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) <-- defiantly
- [C# ftp project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class)

will be useful to you.

I will paste the relevent information from the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class).
None of this code is mine, however it will do what you require.
Just remember to upload the file back to the android system once you're done with it.

```
/* Download File */
    public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
            /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, actually the file is on Android tablet and i am using an app for android to have its ftp control on my system. The system and tablet storage are on same network

Comment: @JibranKhan you should edit your question with that information, it's quite critical to know, every one will assume you are using 2 windows machines because of c# / .net, saying that, I don't yet know how to access a file on an android system from a windows system.

Comment: @JibranKhan I am quite confident that the CodeProject C# ftp link will be exactly what you need :)

Comment: thanks for your assist, i will try it and seems to be exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Thank you @Serdalis, i have successfully achieved what i wanted. Thanks you again.

Comment: Code Project code helped to get the job done, for those who want the same can refer to that article

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file like this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"\\192.168.1.1\FileName.txt");
```

and that will give you back a `string[]`, or like this:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"\\192.168.1.1\FileName.txt"))
{
    ...
}
```

line by line. And you can append to a file (new lines for example) like this:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"\\192.168.1.1\FileName.txt", "Hello, World!");
```

and there are so many other ways. Leverage the `System.Io` namespace.